# Unable to make SSL connection using PHP Curl

Tags: php

I have a php script used to make a connection to a SSL website.
I have both `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` set to `FALSE`
and the version of openssl is up-to-date. (`SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1c`)

When I send a request to that SSL website, it yields the following error:

`string 'error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol' (length=67)`

I've racked my brain all day but still can't solve it. Please help!

===update===

here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.example.com',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Your target site may not be expecting HTTP traffic on the port you are using. Check the documentation for the service you are connection to.

Comment: The SSL verification should not be disabled. Moreover, in this case, that doesn't seem to be the cause of the issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a file within same server, you can use following block of code to fulfill your requirement:

```
ob_start();
require "b.php";
$result = ob_get_clean();
```